# Could HBase CoProcessor scan the whole table?

Tags: hbase

I am using HBase 1.0.1, following are two method signature of coprocessorService:

```
  <T extends Service, R> void coprocessorService(final Class<T> service,
    byte[] startKey, byte[] endKey, final Batch.Call<T,R> callable,
    final Batch.Callback<R> callback) throws ServiceException, Throwable;

  <T extends Service, R> Map<byte[],R> coprocessorService(final Class<T> service,
    byte[] startKey, byte[] endKey, final Batch.Call<T,R> callable)
    throws ServiceException, Throwable;
```

From its javadoc, it looks that the Service code will be run on each table region.And, if I do scan in the service code, each scan will be limited within the region?

Is it possible that I scan the whole table(not just the region that the service code runs) in the service code?